# Scraping table with random selectors

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from [here](https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2017/results/). I need to have results sorted as per their date. But when I look closely I see they  don't have generic selectors, to select rows with same date.

I have tried using bs4 and xpath in Selenium but unable to figure out anything.

Is there exists any way to do this using selenium or bs4.

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: first use bs4/xpath to get all rows and later create for-loop which checks every row and: if there is date then create new list/directory for data, if there is other row then add it to last created list/data.

Comment: @DebanjanB I tried things on console of browser using querySelectorAll(), I wrote few snippets python but later overwrote them as they were not working. :(

Comment: @furas your answer makes sense, I will try this,

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest thing to do will to get the entire table on each page using `soup.find('table', {'id' : 'tournamentTable'}`. You will have to iterate over each page and use pandas to `df.merge()` all of the data together. Once you do that, use `datetime` to turn the date as string into a date object that you can sort within python.

Comment: can you pls elaborate the how this will keep the matches under that date, in it.